# Kernel Installed but Not Running 16.04.4 LTS

Tags: 16.04, apt, grub2, kernel, update-manager

Software updater installed latest kernel 4.4.0-130, I then rebooted but was unable to find it in the grub advanced settings menu.  I looked for it, and determined it was not running:

```
dpkg -l | grep linux-image
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-109-generic               4.4.0-109.132                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-112-generic               4.4.0-112.135                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-116-generic               4.4.0-116.140                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-119-generic               4.4.0-119.143                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-121-generic               4.4.0-121.145                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-image-4.4.0-122-generic               4.4.0-122.146                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic               4.4.0-124.148                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic               4.4.0-127.153                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-128-generic               4.4.0-128.154                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-130-generic               4.4.0-130.156                                amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

uname -r 
4.4.0-128-generic
```

I then ran Grub Customizer, where the new kernel was listed, saved the new config and rebooted again.  The new kernel is still not running.  I then opened terminal and ran:

```
sudo update-grub
```

I rebooted again with the same result.

Update: -128 and -130 appear to boot but hang just before desktop interface as though cascade failures each previous kernel is having boot issues now. Currently running 4.4.0-124

How should I proceed to troubleshoot and make the new kernel run as it normally would after this kind of update?  Can I purge -130 and then re-install the update via apt?  What is a safe way to do that?

Edit per request:

```
:~$ df
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             1900716         0   1900716   0% /dev
tmpfs             384252      6096    378156   2% /run
/dev/sda6       40197496   8797872  29334628  24% /
tmpfs            1921244     45500   1875744   3% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         4      5116   1% /run/lock
tmpfs            1921244         0   1921244   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0         38528     38528         0 100% /snap/handbrake-jz/132
/dev/loop2         38528     38528         0 100% /snap/handbrake-jz/133
/dev/loop1        142848    142848         0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/loop3         38656     38656         0 100% /snap/handbrake-jz/134
/dev/loop6         89088     89088         0 100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop4         88704     88704         0 100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop5         89088     89088         0 100% /snap/core/4830
/dev/sda7      502672688 410111864  71567120  86% /home
tmpfs             384252        88    384164   1% /run/user/1000
:~$ df -i
Filesystem       Inodes  IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev             475179    521   474658    1% /dev
tmpfs            480311    756   479555    1% /run
/dev/sda6       2564096 339157  2224939   14% /
tmpfs            480311    147   480164    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs            480311      3   480308    1% /run/lock
tmpfs            480311     16   480295    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/loop0          511    511        0  100% /snap/handbrake-jz/132
/dev/loop2          502    502        0  100% /snap/handbrake-jz/133
/dev/loop1        27651  27651        0  100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/64
/dev/loop3          503    503        0  100% /snap/handbrake-jz/134
/dev/loop6        12842  12842        0  100% /snap/core/4917
/dev/loop4        12841  12841        0  100% /snap/core/4650
/dev/loop5        12841  12841        0  100% /snap/core/4830
/dev/sda7      31932416 117242 31815174    1% /home
tmpfs            480311     37   480274    1% /run/user/1000
:~$
```

Reinstall Output:

```
:~$ sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic
[sudo] password for x: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-124 linux-headers-4.4.0-124-generic
  linux-headers-4.4.0-127 linux-headers-4.4.0-127-generic
  linux-image-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-4.4.0-127-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-124-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-127-generic
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 reinstalled, 0 to remove and 10 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/2,532 B of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
(Reading database ... 316411 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-generic_4.4.0.130.136_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-image-generic (4.4.0.130.136) over (4.4.0.130.136) ...
Setting up linux-image-generic (4.4.0.130.136) ...
:~$
```

After reboot:

```
:~$ uname -r
4.4.0-130-generic
:~$
```

I rebooted 10 times with same **SOLVED RESULT** also tested previous kernels back to -124, observed zero (hard boot) hangs just prior to desktop interface.  Apparently this solved my problems user535733, if you restate your thoughts as a posted answer I would be happy to provide you the  credit.  I will study this more for future reference and edification.

Comment: I would hit <E> at the grub menu and look at the choice (does it mentioned -130 or not)?  I'd also look and see if what you saw matches your `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` because maybe you have two grubs installed (an old /boot partition; dual boot etc).  *To ensure -130 runs you can use the first edit to make it boot, but it won't help your troubleshooting*.   My first steps anyway

Comment: Since -136 (not -130) is the current kernel for 16.04, I suspect that you are seeing only one symptom. Please edit your question to include the complete output of `df` and `df -i`.

Comment: @user535733 `df` and `df -i` posted, fyi Software Updater indicates it has new updates (Green icon on dash) when clicked there is zero things listed to install with Install Now button highlighted. First time I ever have seen that.  I am not updating until this current situation is sorted out or as part of the solution to the issue(s).

Comment: Try `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic`, and please show us the output. It should install the latest kernel (-136). If it works, try booting into 136. If it fails, seeing the error messages will be essential.

Comment: @user535733 I provided output of reinstall, my machine shows no instability once again, thanks for the help, oh and please post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The first clear problem** is that you don't have the latest kernel installed: Your latest is -130 while Ubuntu is currently distributing -136. The most common reason for this kind of problem is that your `linux-image-generic` metapackage is out-of-date.

Solution: Use `sudo apt install --reinstall linux-image-generic` to refresh the metapackage which will, in turn, pull in the latest kernel for your release of Ubuntu.

You seem to have had another, **more vague second problem** with several symptoms:

- Stale `linux-image-generic` metapackage
- Kernels installing, but not showing in GRUB

There are several possible causes for these symptoms together:

- Out of disk space in `/` or `/boot`:  Check with `df`
- Out of disk inodes: Check with `df -i`
- Apt conflict: Look at apt error messages

Disk space and apt problems usually don't clear up on their own. It seems likely that you did something --whether you know it or not-- to resolve the problem.

Comment: FYI, I don't appear to be out of disk space for `/` or `/boot` and file term.log doesn't show apt errors.   I have looked for 4.4.0-136 and can't find it but for now the problems seem to be gone.  Thanks for the help.